# How to print out in python classes

Tags: python, class

I was tried to figure it out, but I am stucks. I have this scripts

```
 class Myname():
     def first_name(self):
         print("it's Mark")
     def last_name(self):
         print ("it's Anthony")

 class Myself():
     def speak(self):
         print ("I'm Speaking")
     def __init__(self):
         self.speak = Myname()
     def say(self,word):
         print (word)


 me = Myself()

 me.speak.first_name()
```

that script show :

```
it's Mark
```

but when I put this:

```
me.speak()
```

then occurs this

```
TypeError: 'Myname' object is not callable
```

any solution, please ?

Answer (score 3):

You use `speak` twice, a function definition and an attribute. When you say `me.speak()`, it tries to call the attribute which is not callable.

Rename one of them:

```
def speak2(self):
    print ("I'm Speaking")
```

Then call it with the new name:

```
me.speak2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the method speak() in class Myself.

Code (in python shell):

```
>>> class Myname():
...      def first_name(self):
...          print("it's Mark")
...      def last_name(self):
...          print ("it's Anthony")
...
>>> class Myself():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.speak = Myname()
...     def say(self,word):
...         print (word)
...
>>>
```

Execution Output:

```
    >>> me = Myself()
    >>>
    >>> me.speak.first_name()
    it's Mark
    >>>
```

Comment: `me.speak.first_name()` works without deleting `speak()`, because when you say `me.speak.first_name()`, it doesn't call `speak`, just uses it. OP wants to use `me.speak()`.